# How far stretched is the undead mind affecting immunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The undead template from pathfinder tells the following about undead:

- Immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms).

What I'm currently not sure about is: How far stretched is this immunity?

*Thus are undead immune vs. persuasion / seduction attempts? And are they immune vs. mind affecting spells and supernatural powres?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are immune to anything and everything that says it is mind-affecting. That includes [all enchantment spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Enchantment), plenty of non-enchantment spells, morale bonuses, large numbers of spell-like and supernatural abilities, and [all fear effects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Fear_Su_or_Sp) including [the entirety of the Intimidate skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/intimidate/) (see FAQ sidebar).

Whether or not “persuasion / seduction attempts” are mind-affecting depends on what rules, exactly, you are using for that. Certainly all magical forms of these things are mind-affecting. Unfortunately, it is entirely *unclear* whether or not Diplomacy and Bluff are technically mind-affecting, and thus cannot be used against undead.

Comment: for the diplomacy / bluff...that goes into the persuasoin / seduction attempts direction though (as it is the diplomacy skill usually that is used for that)

Comment: @ThomasE. Well unfortunately, I could find no official statements one way or the other from Paizo on the subject of whether or not you can use Bluff or Diplomacy on undead. That question has been a point of contention for some time, going back to 3.5. The kind of thing you would have hoped Paizo would clarify, but oh well.

Comment: tbh it makes sense for mindles undead that they are immune vs. that but for vampires..... guess that will be up to campaign rules each.

Comment: Could you please provide a source to your answer? Where exactly is it written this way?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy The relevant rule is literally quoted in the question: undead are said to be immune to “mind-affecting effects.” All I’ve done is list some of the things that have the “mind-affecting” tag applied to them. I’ll add links to some of the more concrete ones, I guess, but really this is kind of just confirming that this ability does what it says it does.

Comment: @KRyan I'll accept your answer tehre but it could be that I will make an addon question soon, as I'm still wondering there about vampires and other intelligent undead (like mentioned the idea that a vampire can neither be lied to nor persuaded sounds strange to me, but I want to do some background work there first before I decide if I ask there a follow up questoin).

Comment: What happens if a mind affecting spell isnt a charm, compulsion, morale effect, pattern or phantasm? Are they still immune? Like the psionic Mind Thrust thats "telepathy [mind-affecting]"

Comment: @Duncan Yes. Those are still mind-affecting.

Answer (score 6):

**Things intelligent undead are immune to (that are relevant to this question):**

- Any spell, spell-like ability, supernatural ability, or extraordinary ability that has the *mind-affecting* descriptor
- Any spell or spell-like ability belonging to the *charm, compulsion, pattern,* or *phantasm* subschool
- Any supernatural or extraordinary ability that produces a *charm, compulsion, pattern,* or *phantasm* effect (as stated specifically in that ability's description)
- Morale bonuses

**Things unintelligent undead are immune to (that are relevant to this question):**

- All of the above
- Diplomacy checks

Since neither the skill descriptions of Bluff and Diplomacy nor the undead traits make mention of not using social skills against intelligent undead, it's assumed that this is allowed. (While you could make the argument that you can Bluff a mindless undead, why would it care what you have to say?)

If this seems a bit unintuitive, think of it this way: Seduction and persuasion are about convincing a vampire to agree with you. Mind-affecting abilities are about *forcing* a vampire to agree with you (magically or at least supernaturally), to which they're immune.

Comment: Can you clarify if this is "common sense" based ruling you'd make in your game, or if there are rules that back your interpretation that non-magical effects bypass immunity to mind-affecting?  Is it just that you are claiming that *mind-affecting* should be treated as a keyword, and Bluff/Diplomacy lacks that keyword?  Where does immunity to Diplomacy show up from, if not from that rule?  Basically, I'm asking for the reasoning behind your claims (I'm not disputing them).

Comment: I'm treating "mind-affecting" as a keyword that an effect either has or doesn't have, because if you don't, it raises a whole lot more questions than it answers. (Is a convincing argument "mind-affecting"? A well-written poem? A disguise?) The Diplomacy immunity of *un*intelligent undead comes from the skill description-- it can only be used on creatures with an Intelligence of 4 or more.

Comment: Perfectly fair -- can you edit that assumption into your answer?  The conclusions are reasonable, but how you drew them is valuable.